# Set in a Metrizable Space is Closed

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be some metrizable space, $U$ some open set in $X$, and $n \in \Bbb{N}$. Define $S_n(U) := \{x \in X \mid B(x,\frac{1}{n}) \subseteq U \}$. I am trying to show that this set is closed. Here is one of many abysmal attempts:

Suppose that $z \in \overline{S_n(U)}$. I'm not sure what to choose $\epsilon > 0$ to be, but it seems that the only thing that would work is to take $\epsilon < \frac{1}{n}$. Then there exists an $x \in B(z,\frac{1}{n}) \cap S_n(U)$, which means that $d(x,z) < \epsilon < \frac{1}{n}$ and $B(x,\frac{1}{n}) \subseteq U$. If we try to show that $B(z,\frac{1}{n})$, this won't work: suppose $y \in B(z,\frac{1}{n})$; then $d(x,y) \le d(x,z) + d(z,y) < \epsilon + \frac{1}{n}$, where $\epsilon + \frac{1}{n} > \frac{1}{n}$ for every $\epsilon > 0$, which indicates that it isn't necessarily the case that $B(z,\frac{1}{n}) \subseteq B(x,\frac{1}{n})$, which was my only hope of showing $B(z,\frac{1}{n}) \subseteq U$.

As I said, this was a pretty abysmal attempt. I tried out several other ideas (e.g., proof by contradiction, trying to write $S_n(U)$ as the preimage of a closed set under a continuous map, and others), but all of them were unsuccessful. I could use a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Suppose that $U$ is not empty, and not equal to $X$. Let $V=X-U$ the complement of $U$ in $X$. Put $f(x)=d(x,V)={\rm inf}\{d(x,v), v\in V\}$. Then your set is $f^{-1}([\frac{1}{n},+\infty[)$.

Comment: Ah! Okay. So I was close (but not close enough) with my other attempt. Doesn't this proof show that $S_n(U)$ is closed for any nonempty subset $U$, not necessarily open?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

$$S_n(U) = \left\{x \in X \mid d(x,U^c) \ge \frac{1}{n}\right\} = d(\cdot,U^c)^{-1}\left(\left[\frac{1}{n},\infty\right)\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be a limit point of $S_n(U)$ and let $(x_k)_k$ be a sequence with $x_k\in S_n(U)$ for every $k$ and $\lim_{k\to\infty}x_k=x$.

Assume that $x\notin S_n(U)$.

Then some $y$ exists with $y\notin U$ and $d(x,y)<\frac1n$.

Then, since $d(-,y):X\to\mathbb R$ is a continuous map,  for $k$ large enough we also get $d(x_k,y)<\frac1n$  contradicting that $x_k\in S_n(U)$.

So the assumption $x\notin S_n(U)$ must be wrong, and we conclude that $x\in S_n(U)$.

Proved is now that $S_n(U)$ contains its limit points hence is closed.

Comment: So, the basic idea is that, because $d(x_k, y) \ge \frac{1}{n}$ for every $k \in \Bbb{N}$ (otherwise $y \in B(x_k,\frac{1}{n}) \subseteq U$ for some $k$), it must be the case that $\frac{1}{n} > d(x,y) = \lim_{k \to \infty} d(x_k,y) \ge \frac{1}{n}$, which is a contradiction?

Comment: The basic idea is that on base of the assumption $x\notin S_n(U)$ we found a $k$ such that $B(x_k,\frac1n)$ is not a subset of $U$. This because $y\in B(x_k,\frac1n)$ and $y\notin U$. This contradicts $x_k\in S_n(U)$ so the assumption $x\notin S_n(U)$ must be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

[Prove that the following set is closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2666991/prove-that-the-following-set-is-closed)

I’ve answered your question with a different proof in the above thread.